# How to access specific model in rails config/production.rb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, production-environment, rails-4-2-1

I want to send exception mail to email_ids stored in **yb_notifier_email_ids** table. Previously, email_id was hardcoded in **production.rb** file. I want to send mail by using model. But as configurations file are loaded before active_records I am not able to do this.

-----------migration

```
        class CreateYbNotifierEmailIds < ActiveRecord::Migration
          def change
            create_table :yb_notifier_email_ids do |t|
              t.string :email_id

              t.timestamps null: false
            end
          end
        end
```

----------------------------required------------

```
        config.middleware.use ExceptionNotification::Rack,
            :email => {
              :email_prefix => "[YB] ",
              :sender_address => %{"YB Notifier" <noreply@yb.com>},
              :exception_recipients => YbNotifierEmailIds.pluck(:email_id)
            }
        end
```

-----------------------I have tried this:

```
        Rails.application.middleware.use ExceptionNotification::Rack,
              :email => {
                :email_prefix => "[YB-QA] ",
                :sender_address => %{"YB Notifier" <noreply@yb.com>},
                :exception_recipients => defined?(YbNotifierEmailId) && YbNotifierEmailId.table_exists? ? YbNotifierEmailIds.pluck(:email_id) : %w{test@ssolution.com}
        
            }
```

---

but `defined?(YbNotifierEmailId) && YbNotifierEmailId.table_exists?` this condition is getting failed.

Comment: have you tried using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.present? and YbNotifierEmailId.table_exists?`

Comment: Tried but its breaking during deployment. getting below error: ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: No connection pool for ActiveRecord::Base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved using lambda. lambda {TableName.pluck(:email_id)}. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered moving this code to an initializer (*i.e.* a new file under the `config/initializers` folder) just containing your setup code for the middleware?

You'll have access to the models in code run at this point. You'll probably need the form `Rails.application.middleware.use`, per your last example ("have tried this:") - that *should* work, though I haven't explicitly checked this.

Something like a file named `config/initializers/exception_notification.rb` containing just your middleware setup:

```
Rails.application.middleware.use ExceptionNotification::Rack,
  :email => {
    :email_prefix => "[YB] ",
    :sender_address => %{"YB Notifier" <noreply@yb.com>},
    :exception_recipients => YbNotifierEmailIds.pluck(:email_id)
  }
```

Comment: It works, Thanks. But after changing folder I am facing another problem. As I have different host name for production, staging and development environment, for all these environments I have separate files like **production.rb.qa** , **production.rb.prod** etc....but after moving it to initializers folder and changing file name as exception_notification.rb.qa , email is not generated.

Comment: Just use a case statement in the initiatializer, _e.g._ `case Rails.env when "development" then ... development specific code ... when "production"  ... end` - or whatever you need to detect and switch the code per environment. If you want to get super funky, use `require "production.rb.qa"` in the environment specific section of your `case` statement - though you might need to change the name of those files to something like `production_qa.rb`. They will also have to be outside of the `initializers` folder otherwise they will get added automatically. Does that help/make sense?

Comment: Noticed another issue after moving it to initializer folder, whenever I am adding new email_id to the database table , email has not been received to that user until I deployed. After adding any Email_id I have to do deployement now.

Comment: Yep, because the initializer code is only run once - when the app starts.

Comment: In that case, it won't be feasible because every time for any new record we can't do deployment. Do you have any another solution?

Comment: Nothing easy. It looks like someone has had a go at making the list of recipients a proc, but I've no idea how well this works (in terms of lazy evaluation): https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification/pull/330

Comment: this won't do as we need to get the email ids from the database table which maybe updated while the application runs.

Comment: The proc based solution should work, as it appears to evaluate each time in the `compose_email` method within the `EmailNotifier` class. If not, you may just have to monkey-patch that method or the `maybe_call` method (the wrapper around the proc) to return the list of recipients dynamically. See https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification/blob/master/lib/exception_notifier/email_notifier.rb#L151

Comment: This is resolved using lambda.